# How to assign hexColor code to any datatype on java class file

Tags: java, android, user-interface, colors, hex

I need to change a textColor on the UI scrolling.
What i've done is I've declared the colors into Colors.xml files.

```
<color name="color1">#e0195c</color>
<color name="color2">#7f26db</color>
<color name="color3">#1d38df</color>
<color name="color4">#1b1b1d</color>
<color name="color5">#232428</color>
```

And i am trying to use them by using following code:

textView.setTextColor(getResource().getColor(R.color.color1));

But during execution some of them are not working. like color1 is not working.

Its throwing exception :- String #e0195c conversion error

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: You may have given 'o' instead of zero (0), are you sure about it

Answer (score 2):

You can set the color dynamically like

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e0195c"));
```

Its working for me. And i am not getting any Exception.

Now i created an Array for Color code

```
private String[] colorHexCode = {"#e0195c", "#7f26db", "#1d38df"}; 

textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorHexCode[0]));
```

So you can change the color by using array also.

Comment: I updated my answer as your requirement. You can take a look. Thanks